# Jsp lify cycle methods why jspService() method is start with the "_" character

Tags: jsp

There are three life cycle methods of JSP

```
1) jspInit();
2) _jspService();
3) jspDestroy();
```

but here the why  jspService() method is start with the "_" character.

Comment: as it goes out of the standar java naming convention could be a  way to suggest that _should never be defined by the JSP page author_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it deviates from the standard Java naming convention, it could be a way to suggest that *should never be defined by the JSP page author*.

As per the other methods:

- When a container loads a JSP it invokes the `jspInit()` method before servicing any requests. If you need to perform JSP-specific initialization, override the `jspInit()` method:

  ```
  public void jspInit(){
    ...
  }
  ```
- The `jspDestroy()` method is the JSP equivalent of the destroy method for servlets. Override `jspDestroy` when you need to perform any cleanup, such as releasing database connections or closing open files. This method has the following form:

  ```
  public void jspDestroy(){
  ...
  }
  ```

However these methods are not required anymore as you should not use scripting anymore. Please consider better alternatives as [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).